# Accessing remotely files in the same network

Tags: http, curl, command-line, wget

I'm trying to access some files remotely using wget, curl over HTTP protocol, but I'm geting only "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found"

The files I'm need to access are located in the folder /var/www/html and the Apache2 machine with Ubuntu is started. From another Ubuntu machine I tried the following:

When I use the following commands I get "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found"

`wget "http://222.168.xx.xxx:80/var/www/html/4?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=dns.log"`

`curl -v http://222.168.xx.xxx:80/var/www/html/dns.log`

Trying the following command, I get only a index.html file: 
`wget 192.168.xx.xxx dns.log`

Could any one tell me, please, what I'm doing wrong? How can I access remotely a file using line command?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`/var/www/` is the "document root", so the site starts serving documents from that directory.

In other words: `http://222.168.xx.xxx:80/` already points to `/var/www`, no need to include the latter in the request URI.

Answer (score 0):

The right way to make the request with curl is :
`curl http://222.168.xx.xxx/file_to_download`

with telnet:
`telnet 222.168.xx.xxx 80
GET \file_to_download HTTP\1.0`